# Decidability of Wilf Equivalence

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, algebraic-combinatorics

I have seen a lot of papers discussing whether various permutation classes are [Wilf equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilf_equivalence) to each other. I wonder if we could solve such problems in general with computers.

More rigorously, let $\mathcal{L}$ be the language
$$\{(S_1, S_2): \text{the permutation classes avoiding permutations in $S_i$ are Wilf Equivalent.}\}$$
This language is clearly recognizable by enumerating every permutation in the two classes. My question is whether we know anything about the decidability of this language.

Comment: Have you tried asking this question on MathOverflow?